# SQL get multiple values (from the same column from same table) from table with 2 foreign keys to the first table

Tags: mysql, sql

Users Table has two columns, Id And Name
PurchasedCars Table has 4 columns, LicensePlate, Owner's Id, Seller's Id, and selling price that isn't relevant.

For an example i got this data
Users
(1, Josh)
(2, Jonathan)
(3, Or)
(4, Jacob)

Cars
(123, irrelevant data)
(456, irrelevant data)
(789, irrelevant data)

PurchasedCars
(123, 2, 1, 50k)
(456, 3, 1, 80k)
(789, 4, 1, 30k)

Output
(123, Jonathan, Josh)
(456, Or, Josh)
(789, Jacob, Josh)

I got three tables the first table is a table of users and the second table is a table of sold cars both the owner and seller are foreign keys to Id in users and i need to get the name of each of them to the same record set.

and the return of the query would be LicensePlate, Owner's name, Worker's name

### SQL CODE

```
Select Cars.LicensePlate From Cars
Union 
Select Users.Name as WorkerName From Users, PurchasedCars 
Where Users.Id=PurchasedCars.Seller
Union
Select Users.Name as BuyerName From Users, PurchasedCars 
Where Users.Id=PurchasedCars.Owner
```

Comment: `I got to tables` ... I see _three_, not two, tables in your query.  Please add sample data and the expected output.

Comment: just added picture with information and output

Comment: I was able to answer your question based on your screen capture link, but your question is still not idea.  Please delete that link, and instead include all relevant data directly in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join twice against users, once for owner and once for seller

```
SELECT p.licensePlate, u1.name as 'Workers name', u2.name as 'Sellers name'
FROM PurchacedCars p
JOIN Users u1 ON p.seller = u1.id
JOIN Users u2 ON p.owner = u2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is to just join `Users` to `PurchasedCars` twice, once for each name:

```
SELECT
    pc.LicensePlate,
    u1.Name AS worker_name,
    u2.Name AS owner_name
FROM PurchasedCars pc
INNER JOIN Users u1
    ON pc.Seller = u1.Id
INNER JOIN Users u2
    ON pc.Owner = u2.Id;
```

[image]

### Demo